# Iphone main thread crashes but app still running - "program received signal 0"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, memory-leaks

so when i'm running my app using XCode and I can see that my app gets "program received signal 0".
However , the background thread are still running. why is that ?

Second, I can't seem to find any solution to this problem.
I assumed it might be memory leak, but I see nothing special using LEAKS (instrument).

When I run the app on the device(without XCode) and then try to see the device crash inside the organizer, most of the times there is no log (I guess maybe because the app is still running and only the main thread crashed) and while there is a log, my app function are only hex addresses without names.

What other options do I have to solve this issues ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you try to clean and build the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that sometimes these errors are caused by trying to access deallocated memory.  One great tool to debug these issues is NSZombieEnabled.  Here's a link to a good explanation of how to use NSZombieEnabled: [CocoaDev: NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled)

Comment: Thanks but already using it. it's not the problem, I know almost 100% that the ios is shutting my app down. Just have no clue how to find the leak.

Comment: You know what, funny as it may sound, but I think those leaks were exactly because of the NSZombie!

Comment: @Idan Hi i got the same problem my app exits with status 0,i had also enabled NSZombie but not found any solution,is that so that NSZombie is creating my app to exit.Please let me know thanks.

Comment: Probably so. When you enable NSZombie your app won't release anything, so eventually if you allocate alot of objects , it might crash like it happened to me.